# What is the proper way to prevent a program from exiting after a user enters wrong input in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop

**The Task**

> Design and implement an application that reads an integer value and prints out the sum of all EVEN integers between 2 and its input value, inclusive. Print an error message if the input value is less than 2.  Prompt accordingly.
>
> **Note: the lesson was on while loops, not other loops such as *for loop* etc**

**The Issue**

I have everything working, however something about how I have written this feels wrong. I currently have a while loop `while(programOn)` to keep the program running. without this while loop, if the user enters a number `< 2`, the user is asked to try again, however if the user tries again, the program exits instead of running the new input into the program. So, I created the while loop to force the program open until the user types an acceptable input.

*- something about this feels hacky and incorrect i would really appreciate some validation on my method.*

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int inputNumber;
int sum = 0;

boolean programOn = true;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please Type a number no smaller than 2");
inputNumber = scan.nextInt();

//include the original input to sum
sum = inputNumber;

while(programOn){
    if(inputNumber < 2){
      System.out.println("you need a number greater than or equal to 2, try again");

      inputNumber = scan.nextInt();
      sum = inputNumber;

    }else{

    //from the number chosen divide until you reach 0

    while(inputNumber != 0){

      //subtract one from the number
      inputNumber = (inputNumber - 1);

      if((inputNumber % 2 == 0) && (inputNumber != 0)){
        System.out.println(inputNumber);
        //add the input to the sum
        sum += inputNumber;
      }
    }
      System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
      programOn = false;
  }
}


}
```

Comment: What input would the user have to give as to leave the loop as planned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the validation is done by an `if` condition. What you need here is a `while` loop that keeps asking for inputs as long as user's `input` is `less than` 2, below is the code snippet that does this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please Type a number no smaller than 2");
int inputNumber = scan.nextInt();

while(inputNumber < 2){
    System.out.println("you need a number greater than or equal to 2, try again");
    inputNumber = scan.nextInt();
}

System.out.println(inputNumber);
```

Comment: But better solution if he move `scan.nextInt()` inside main while loop. In this case his validation will work correctly without second while loop. Maybe provide better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems so obvious now. Is it okay to have two while loops? for example one like the example you gave and then another one under it for 'inputNumber != 0' ? or is there a more elegant way of writing this?

Comment: @eg04lt3r Are you refering to the while(programOn) or the while(inputNumber < 2)? thank you

Comment: @cdm89 you don't need outer `while` loop anymore. This should take care of inputs.

Comment: @eg04lt3r we don't need `while(programOn)` anymore

Comment: @DarshanMehta Sorry I dont understand, removing the outter programon loop... i still need two while loops, but not nested correct? one for inputNumer less than 2 and one for inputNumber != 0 ?

Comment: @DarshanMehta, yeah, you are right. For his requirement there is should be only on loop with check of input correctness.